# Calling an Azure AD Protected API from Logic App using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

We are having an Azure AD Protect API which is hosted on prem. We have a requirement to call this API from Logic App. We have currently created or registered a new client App in App Registration for this logic App and have provided the necessary permissions and have called API passing the Bearer Token.

My question, is there a way we can leverage Managed Identity for Logic App (either User Assigned or System Assigned) for calling the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.
I wrote an article on the topic (though it is not specific to Logic Apps): https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions.

You will need to create an *appRoleAssignment* that gives an application permission to your managed identity service principal.
To do this, we must use PowerShell or Microsoft Graph API.
With [Azure AD PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD), we can do this:

```
Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $miSpId -Id $appRoleId -PrincipalId $miSpId -ResourceId $targetApiSpId
```

There we have 3 arguments you need to find:

1. miSpId: The objectId of the Managed Identity (easy, we can find this from the Identity blade in the Logic App)
2. appRoleId: The id of the appRole defined on your API's manifest (this should be easy to find as well, it's in your API's manifest)

   - If you haven't defined an appRole (app permission) on your API, you will need to do that first (https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad)
3. targetApiSpId: The objectId of the target API service principal (this one you can get by going to Enterprise Applications and finding your API there)