# Azure Logic App - how to call an API authenticated by Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-logic-apps

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is secured by Azure AD and exposes a few APIs for me.

I would like to invoke these APIs using Logic Apps (for a few reasons).

I have no idea how I can invoke these authenticated APIs in Logic Apps using the Designer. I basically want to invoke the API using a specific user such that I can lock down the APIs to one or two users instead of the entire tenancy.

This is the logic app:

[image]

I'm not sure what the Authentication Type should be that will allow me to invoke the API.

The API simply looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
```

And simply exposes to some GET requests.

Any ideas? Happy to elaborate if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you need to use a user at all?  Have you looked into using a Managed Identity?

Comment: Preferably a user because this way I can lock down who can invoke the API.. because there may be a need for specific users in the platform to also invoke those APIs down the line

Comment: You could always take both approaches, no harm in having a system managed identity from LogicApps given that's the specific issue you're asking to solve.  If it's a user based call to the API then you can tackle that at a later stage with a specific user group.  All can be achieved.  I'd read up on the managed identity model, it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the above requirement by adding managed identity to your logic app as suggested by @*Skin*,

Kindly note that before adding managed identity , enable managed idenity provider to your logic app then select the authentication type as managed identity.

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

---

[image]

For more information please refer the below Links:-

***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Increase security for calls to custom APIs from Azure Logic Apps***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication)

***SO THREAD:-*** [***Calling an Azure AD Protected API from Logic App using Managed Identity***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431403/calling-an-azure-ad-protected-api-from-logic-app-using-managed-identity)